# ¿Cómo ocupo el valor de una una función que usa paso de parámetros en otro función de la misma clase?

Tags: php

quisiera ver si alguien me pudiera ayudar con esto:

Tengo una clase llamada "ejemplo", en la cual tengo dos funciones, una que recibe un parámetro (función a) y otro que no (función b) y lo que quiero es poder consumir el parámetro que le paso a la "función a" "con la función b".

Al hacer esto que tengo aquí no obtengo ningún resultado, alguien sabe cómo podría solucionarlo, les agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Saludos.

```
class ejemplo{
public static function a($texto){
    return $texto;
}

public static function b(){
    $nuevo_texto = self::a($texto);

    if($nuevo_texto == "hola"){
        $res = "ok";
    }else{
        $res = "no";
    }
    return $res;
}
```

}

$texto = ejemplo::a('hola');
echo ejemplo::b();

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar lo que pretendes con esto? ¡Es como si quisieras hacer de tu función `a` un *getter*  y un *setter*  al mismo tiempo! O sea, tu función `a` si observas, está recibiendo y retornando lo mismo, ¿qué sentido tiene eso en un contexto real?

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, originalmente busco pasar el identificador de una tienda, posteriormente con ese identificador hacer una condicional donde dependiendo el identificador hacer que una imagen qr tenga cierto color de fondo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder hacer esto, tendrías que:

- Declarar `$texto` como una propiedad estática de la clase
- Al ser estática, puedes definirla sin necesidad de llamar a una función para ello, bastaría con algo como `ejemplo::$propiedadEstatica='valor';`
- Entonces podrás consumirla en `b()`

Por ejemplo:

```
class ejemplo{
    static $mTexto;

    public static function b(){
        return (self::$mTexto == "hola") ? "ok" : "no";
    }
}
```

Ahora usemos la clase:

```
ejemplo::$mTexto='hola';  
echo ejemplo::b();  # ok
```

---

```
ejemplo::$mTexto='holas';  
echo ejemplo::b();  # no
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, soluciono mi problema. Eres un crack!

Comment: @CésarAugusto revisa la respuesta editada. Si declaras una propiedad como estática, puedes modificarla directamente, prescindiendo de la función `a()`.

Comment: Súper, aún mejor. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y la información. Me ha servido de mucho.